# Returning nested custom classes from Spring JPA, Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a `Student` class.

```
@Entity
public class Student {
  private long id;
  private String name;
  private String department;
  private String subDepartment;
  private int marks;

  //getters, setters and constructors.
}
```

I want to be able to get min, max and average marks grouped by `department` and then `subDepartment`.

My repository:

```
public class StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student,Long> {

 @Query("Select s.department, s.subDepartment , min(marks), max(marks), avg(marks) from Student as s groupby s.department, s.subDepartment")
 List<Object[]> getStatsByDepartmentAndSubDepartment()
}
```

Of course, **this works** but I want to avoid using `List<Object[]>` and instead get something like:

```
Map<String, Map<String,Stats>> class
```

Where first key is `Department`, second key is `subDepartment` and `Stats` class encapsulates min,max,average

Is there a way to do this with `Spring JPA.` ? I checked and nested classes are not possible.

How about `Hibernate` or any other solution? I am a newbie when it comes to `Hibernate`.

I am using `Spring boot` and can add any dependency needed. Any database is ok, even `H2` for a start.

Comment: You can create custom repository with any implementation, please check this: https://vladmihalcea.com/custom-spring-data-repository/

Comment: I don't think there is a way to return a Map instead of a List. You will have to do the conversion from list to map yourself

Comment: @DavideD'Alto, I am fine with getting a List as long as it is not list of Object[]. Do you know how can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot return a map.
You can convert the rows using a class DTO.

### Class DTO with constructor

You can also create a class DTO:

```
class StudentDTO {

    public StudentDTO(String dep, String subDep, Integer min, Integer max, Double avg ) {
       this.stats = new Stats(min, max, avg);
       ...
    }
}
```

And then call it in the select clause:

```
select new StudentDTO(s.department, s.subDepartment, avg(s.marks), ...) from ...
```

This will return a `List<StudentDTO>`.
As long as the constructor matches the select clause, it will work fine.

### Interface DTO

You can also define DTO using interfaces, but I don't think it works if you have nested classes.

This will work though:

```
interface StudentViev {
   String getDepartment();
   String getSubdepartment();
   Integer getMinMark();
   Integer getMaxMark();
   Double getAvgMark();
}
```

and now you can use it as type for the list:

```
 @Query("Select s.department as department, s.subDepartment as subDepartment, min(marks) as minMark, max(marks) as maxMark, avg(marks) as avgMark from Student as s groupby s.department, s.subDepartment")
 List<StudentView> getStatsByDepartmentAndSubDepartment()
```

Note that I've used aliases in the select cluase so that the column names returned match the getters in the interface

Comment: Thank you, this is similar to what I am looking for. Is there some way to use Stats class as part of StudentView (composite)? Reason being, I already have a Stats class that I could use here. To make it easy to understand, I used the trivial Student example, in reality, the project is more complex.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with interfaces, but you can create a class DTO and in the constructor create an object of type Stats

Comment: Thank you, using class based approach (as opposed to Interface) is fine, how would I go about writing the select query for this case?

Comment: Ah, I see the edit now. Thank you. Let me try...